# Div with Iframe (hiding and showing the iframe)

Tags: css, html, iframe

What i would like to do is this:

In my website, i want to have a div in the left corner that, when the mouse is NOT over it, its just a simple square with a color (for now).

For that, i have this code:

```
<div id='bot'>
</div>
```

Its very simple of course, in my css:

```
#bot{
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 40px !important;
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  left:0%;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px;
}

#bot:hover{
  width:500px;
}
```

Ok so for now this does it. Now what i would like to appear on this div when i MOUSEOVERIT, would be it show a iframe:

```
<iframe name='botframe' src='http://demo.vhost.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=a431414a6e34774c' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
```

Is this possible at all? If so, what would i have to do?
I understand a bit of javascript if needed, but no so much of jQuery, so if jQuery is needed please tell me exactly what i must do and where to put the code.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using id for div pls put id for iframe,

```
<div> <iframe **id='bot'** name='botframe' src='http://demo.vhost.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=a431414a6e34774c' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, what would i have to do next?

Edit: so i did that, and i think its almost done, the only thing is, when the mouse is not over it, it still shows a little of the text from the iframe, i would like it not to show anything. I already tried font-size:0px; but it wont work

Comment: jsut use the iframe with id that was styled as 'bot'...:)

Comment: try assign width:0px in #bot style...:)

Answer (score 0):

Lay the div over the iframe, and change the z-index of each on hover.

```
<iframe id='botframe' name='botframe' src='http://placehold.it/50/' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
<div id='bot'></div>

#bot{position:fixed; background:pink; bottom:40px; width:50px; height:150px; left:0; border:1px solid black;}
#botframe {position:fixed; background:yellow; bottom:40px; width:50px; height:150px; left:0; border:1px solid red;}
#bot:hover{z-index:-1;}
#botframe:hover{z-index:100;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gcWeC/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its not working properly, is it working with you, or you didnt test it?

Comment: That fiddle works for me.  What part of it doesn't work for you?  What do you see?

Comment: When i over the mouse on it, it seems like, one div didnt expand and the other did

Comment: Thanks guys i got it work, i work my around it, instead of centering in the left part of the page, i centered on the bottom, and it fits my needs now. Thanks!